# Why does C# Math.Ceiling round down?

Tags: c#, math

I'm having a rough day, but something is not adding up correctly.

In my C# code, I have this:

```
Math.Ceiling((decimal)(this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize))
```

Where `(int)TotalRecordCount` = 12 and `(int)PageSize` = 5. The result I am getting is 2.
(Both values are `int` values.)

By my calculations,  12 / 5 = 2.4. I thought Math.Ceiling would always round up, and in this case, give me 3?

PS, if I do this:

```
Math.Ceiling(this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize)
```

I get the message:

> Math.Ceiling(this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize)
>   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You see "rounding down" because the truncation happens before reaching `Math.Ceiling`.

When you do this

```
(this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize)
```

It is an integer division, and its result is a truncated `int`; it is too late to cast it to `decimal`.

To fix this problem, cast before the division:

```
Math.Ceiling(((decimal)this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize))
```

Answer (score 12):

Because *TotalRecordCount* and *PageSize* is int, and int division rounds down. You have to convert at least one of the operands to decimal to use decimal division:

```
Math.Ceiling((decimal)this.TotalRecordCount / this.PageSize));
```