# C# Calculation of two database columns returns zero

Tags: c#

I am running a simple query and calculating the percentage of two values. Every time this run's the calculation returns zero. The calculation is cast to a decimal also, so I can't see what the problem is.

```
from e in db.hours
select new
{
    OverTimeHoursPercentage = (decimal)((1088 / 22000) * 100)
};
```

After the query is ran, I can see in the debugger, the type of OverTimeHoursPercentage is a `decimal`, and that the value calculated is zero when it should be `4.94`.

Any ideas of whats going on?

Comment: `1088/ 22000` is not `decimal`, it's an `int` division. Add `M` to one of the constants to fix this problem, e.g. `1088M / 22000`

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431095/335858) for a longer explanation.

Comment: @DragandDrop I remember answering a similar question in the past, so I quickly fetched a link to it. I didn't suggest closing this question as a duplicate of the linked Q&A, though, and I am sure that there are better duplicate targets for it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Sorry, Just pointing out that answer here a a bit more explicative and even your comment is clearer that the linked one. It may have sound like i was talking about self promoting  when I was in fact addressing the fact that it was not really a longer explation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1088` and `22000` are integers, and with integer math `1088 / 22000` is `0`.  `0 * 100` is also `0`.  And, when converted to a decimal, `0` is `0.0`.

What you want to do is perform your conversion *before* performing the calculations.  Fortunately you can do this directly in a literal value (at compile time) without having to cast (at run time).  Appending `M` to any one value in the expression should do the trick:

```
(1088M / 22000) * 100
```

or you can explicitly mark them all as decimals:

```
(1088M / 22000M) * 100M
```

With this you can remove the cast, as the result of the decimal expression will itself be a decimal:

```
OverTimeHoursPercentage = (1088M / 22000M) * 100M
```

Answer (score 0):

Dividing 2 integers will produce an integer result, which will lose any of the decimal precision you are looking for.

So you need to make at least one of the values *in the division* a decimal. Casting *after* the calculation is too late, the damage is already done.

Try this:

```
OverTimeHoursPercentage = (((decimal)1088 / 22000)*100)
```

or better still, if it is a literal value, then declare it as a decimal and don't cast (note the `m`):

```
OverTimeHoursPercentage = ((1088m / 22000)*100)
```